# no scripts folder in hardhat framework instead there's ignition folder with a subfolder named modules

Tags: ethereum, blockchain, smartcontracts, ethers.js, hardhat

I have noticed that in my VS Code environment for the Hardhat framework, there is an "ignition" folder instead of a "scripts" folder. Could someone explain why this discrepancy exists and whether these folders serve the same purpose?

I attempted to find information on the difference between them through Google and the official documentation but was unable to find any relevant details.

Thank you for any insights you can provide regarding this matter.